# Gulp build is not working since devDependencies are not installed when NODE_ENV=production

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, babeljs

I have an application in which I am trying to do `npm install` && then `gulp build`. It works fine unless I give NODE_ENV=production since npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.

Following are some snippets.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "aliasify": "^2.0.0",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-plugin-__coverage__": "^11.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0"
}
```

Error

```
[13:10:13] Failed to load external module babel-register
[13:10:13] Failed to load external module babel-core/register
[13:10:13] Failed to load external module babel/register
/path/to/repository/gulpfile.babel.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import gulp from 'gulp';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Since I am trying to build the application for production, babel & its dependencies are not installed. I am not even able to start the build.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I think the `import gulp from 'gulp';` must on the top of the file `/path/to/repository/gulpfile.babel.js` but not in the function block

Comment: Its not in the function block. My gulpfile.babel.js looks like this. `import gulp from 'gulp';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import nodemon from 'gulp-nodemon';
import gulpLoadPlugin from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import './gulp/common';
import './gulp/script';
import './gulp/style';
import './gulp/test';

const gulpSequence = runSequence.use(gulp);
const $ = gulpLoadPlugin();

gulp.task('build', (callback) => {
    gulpSequence('clean', 'preprocess', 'styles', 'scripts', 'resources', 'tmp-del', callback);
});
`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install dev dependencies, you can write gulpfile in es5 and es6 features already supported by nodejs.

Or you can set NODE_ENV after you run  gulp tasks.

Also npm install --only=dev will install dev dependencies regardless of NODE_ENV.

Comment: I thought of doing the same. But the environment variable is set using Jenkins before all the commands are run. Also I have already written entire gulp code in es6. I was looking for a solution where I do not need to write gulpfile in es5.

Comment: @AmitDaga nodejs already support many es6 features, just replace import with require may be enough to work

Comment: @AmitDaga You can try npm install --only=dev, it will install dev dependencies regardless of node_env, but remember to install dependencies too.

Comment: Looks like a better solution.